# Does $\frac{1}{a}F(x)>\frac{1}{c}G(y)$ imply $\frac{1}{a}\int_0^bF(b)>\frac{1}{c}\int_0^dG(d)?$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, functions

Suppose I have two functions $G,F: \mathbb{R}_+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$. I also know that $F'(x)=G'(x)$. Now suppose that the following inequality holds

$$\frac{1}{a}F(b)>\frac{1}{c}G(d)$$

For constants $a,c>0$, and $d>b>0$. Is it true that this implies that

$$\frac{1}{a}\int_0^bF(x)>\frac{1}{c}\int_0^dG(x)?$$

---

Since $F'(x)=G'(x)$, the rates of decrease of functions  $\frac{1}{a}F(b)$ and $\frac{1}{c}G(d)$ in their respective arguments are the same. Hence this implies that for all $x\leq b$ and all $y\leq d$, the following must hold

$$\frac{1}{a}F(x)>\frac{1}{c}G(y)$$

This implies that,

$$\frac{1}{a}\int_0^bF(x)>\frac{1}{c}\int_0^dG(x).$$

Is this correct? If so, how could you rephrase my argument to make it seem more convincing and rigorous? If it is wrong, why?

---

Note that $a$ and $c$ are arbitrary positive constants.

Comment: Just to clarify: In the problem statement, do you want $\frac{1}{a}\int_0^bF(b)>\frac{1}{c}\int_0^dG(d)$ or $\frac{1}{a}\int_0^bF>\frac{1}{c}\int_0^dG$?

Comment: The second I think! Fixed it in the question too.

Comment: @Aweygan Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $F\equiv 1, G\equiv 1$, $a=1,c=2,b=4,d=5$.